# how to connect with another database from repository Class Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to develop two authentication system in a single application. One for admin and another for user. I can connect to default database. But, I could not authenticate the user. I tried this code but its not working.

How to connect to another database from repository class?

**UserRepository.php**

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

        //print_r($request);
        $company_id = $request->get('_company_code');

        $conn = $this->getEntityManager('client')->getConnection();
        $query = $conn
            ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username AND u.company_id= :company_id')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('company_id', $company_id);
            //->getQuery();


        try {
            // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
            // if there is no record matching the criteria.
            $user = $query->getFirstResult();
            //$user = $query->getSingleResult();

            //exit("123");
        } catch (NoResultException $e) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active admin AcmeUserBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

**Config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            client:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                charset:  UTF8
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:

                ESSCompanyBundle: ~
                ESSAdminUserBundle: ~
                ESSUserBundle: ~

        client:
            connection: client
            mappings:
                ESSUserBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest but not as clean solution would be:

```
# Controller code
$repo = ....
$repo->setClientEntityManager( $clientEntityManager );

# Repo code
public function setClientEntityManager(){
    $this->clientEntityManager = $clientEntityManager;
}

public function someRepoFunction(){
    $this->clientEntityManager-> // you do here whatever you'd like
}
```

Better solution would be to declare that repository class to be service and **inject** client entity manager object. (either via `__constuct` or `set*` method)

Comment: I had a project where images (galleries) were located in two separated databases, so I decided to merge them within controller's method. However, if you need to displace your logic to repository's method I would go for **service injection**.